# BabylonJS Ionic app, 3D model not getting loaded

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework, babylonjs

I'm developing a IOS mobile game with BabylonJS and to develop the mobile application Ionic framework will be used. I have added the 3D model to the assets folder and 
 following method is used to load the 3D model.

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("", "", './assets/Man.babylon', scene, function (meshes, particleSystems, skeletons)
```

The 3D model get loaded in the emulator, but it doesn't loaded on the device. Is there special way to access resources in released applications.

Comment: what error it is showing?

Comment: It don't show any errors. but the 3D model do not get loaded. Same issue with Android as well. I added the 3D resource to the www/assets folder in the project structure.

Comment: Did you manage how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at this documentation: http://doc.babylonjs.com/tutorials/babylonjs_and_ionic_angular